# Behat Acceptance Test Identify Response Type

Tags: behat, acceptance-testing

I am writing some tests for my application that is expected to return Json response and i wish to ensure it by using Behat.

```
Scenario: Response is json
    Given I am on the domain "api.mydomain.net"
    When I call the webservice "api" with GET
    Then the webservice response content type is "application/json"
```

I researched at documentation of Behat but couldn't find any useful resource to assert response type.

Does anyone experienced the same situation and came up with a solution?

Comment: Have you tried so save the response in a variable and work from there?

Comment: It depends on how the feature context makes API requests. For example, in step `When I call the webservice "api" with GET`, there could be a HTTP response stored as a property of current feature context instance for later testing step of `Then the webservice response content type is "application/json"`